# JDBI using @bind for variables in queries inside quotes

Tags: objectquery, jdbi

I'm wondering if/how this is possible, if it is, I'm sure its a simple fix that I can't seem to figure out

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column LIKE '%:thingName%'")
public Set<Things> getThings(@Bind("thingName", String thingName)
```

Essentially for this toy example I am trying to select a row where a column contains [any text]thingName[anyText]. When using as above, I think the quotes obscure the bound variable so it literally looks for [any text]**:thingName**[anyText] and not my bound variable.

Thank you in advance,
Madeline

Comment: You should change the accepted answer to the concatenation solution.  There is a way to do this without making code changes that may introduce a bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears to be the case that you must add the '%' percentages to the bound variable:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column LIKE :thingName")
public Set<Things> getThings(@Bind("thingName") String thingName); // where thingName = "%" + thingName + "%"
```

See also: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jdbi/EwUi2jAEPdk

Quote from Brian McCallister

> Using the :foo binding stuff creates a prepared statement and binds in the value for name in this case. You need the % to be part of the bound value, or you need to not use bindings to a prepared statement.
>
> - Approach 1 (the safer and generally better one): 
>     "select … from foo where name like :name" and bind the value ("%" + name)
> - Approach 2 (which opens you up to sql injection):
>
> "select … from foo where name like '%' " and define("name", name)  (or in sql object, (@Define("name") name) -- which puts name in as a literal in your statement.
>
> The key thing is that the % character is part of the *value* you are testing against, not part of the statement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is what I had done, I was hoping there was a better way out there but it seems not. - Madeline

Comment: The answer below using a concatenation operation is a better answer as it doesn't require logical changes.  If you're using postgres, you can do `'%' || :term || '%'

Answer (score 24):

I use concat to surround input with % signs while still using a bound variable to avoid SQL injection:

```
@SqlQuery("select * from atable where acolumn like concat('%',:thingName,'%')")
public Set getNames(@Bind("thingName") String thingName);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This must be the case with LIKE while binding variables. As per JDBI doc([Here](http://jdbi.org/)) using SQL query concatenation can solve the issue. It worked for me.